# startActivity() with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK not always working when called from subclassed Application class

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, android-library, android

I have a method in a subclass of Application that fires off an intent to start an activity.  I send along a string extra with the intent so the newly launched activity knows which fragment to display to the user.

There are a bunch of reasons why I'm starting activities from an Application subclass and 99 times out of 100 it works perfectly.  But every once in a while it just doesn't work.  Everything just stops.

```
public static void showFirstFragment(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getAppContext(), HostActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("displayFragment", "firstFragment");
        getAppContext().startActivity(intent);

        methodThatDoesSomethingElse();
}
```

The subclass of Application belongs to a library project that I'm making available for Unity games on Android so the method showFirstFragment() is actually called from within the game code itself.

As I said, 99 times out of 100 it works perfectly.  No problems whatsoever.  But every once in a while, when the method is called the system just doesn't launch the intent.

After spending all day trying to capture logs of it happening I can guarantee that the context being passed to the intent is not null and that methodThatDoesSomethingElse() gets executed everytime.  Also, methodThatDoesSomethingElse() just sends a tiny bit of data down an open socket.  It does nothing that could possibly interfere with launching the intent.

Here's the log that I was able to capture from one of the times that it just stopped dead:

```
09-25 00:20:31.202: I/ActivityManager(750): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.GamePackage.GameName/com.LibraryPackage.package.HostActivity (has extras)} from pid 19318
09-25 00:20:31.232: D/myLogTag(19318): A log from inside methodThatDoesSomethingElse()
```

When everthing works properly there are of course many more logs and tags from all the work that takes place once HostActivity is launched.  I even have tags in HostActivity's onCreate and onResume and these tags don't get hit when everything stalls like this.  It just stops right there.

I feel like I'm running into just a deep Android system bug and I don't know what to do about it.  Is there some kind of retry policy I can put in for launching intents?  I'm considering putting a bool in Shared Prefs that switches when the HostActivity is started then checking that bool from inside a timer back in the Application subclass so if the bool doesn't change after 2 seconds then relaunch the intent...but man, that's some hacky shit.

I also considered using startActivityForResult but that doesn't send back any kind of 'I failed' signal and I don't need a 'succeeded' signal.

So any ideas on how to make the intent ALWAYS work.  I've never had this problem in any of my other apps.

I'm officially stumped.  It happens so rarely that I can't even test for it.